# When creating a new timer, what will happen to the old?

Tags: c#, system.timers.timer

I have inherit some old code and it looks to me that there is an problem with some part(s) of it.

The program uses TCP/IP to communicate with another program and the protocol is simple. Send a command Telegram and wait for a response telegram.

Here is the part that's I think is problematic.

```
public System.Timers.Timer retransmitTimer;

public TelegramBase SendAndWait(TelegramBase telegram)
{
    CurrentTelegram = telegram;

    retransmitTimer = new Timer(RetransmitInterval);
    retransmitTimer.Elapsed += retransmitTimer_Elapsed;

    //Send telegram
    Send(telegram);

    //Start timer
    retransmitTimer.Start();

    //Wait for response
    var response = WaitForResponse(telegram as StandardTelegram);

    //stop timer
    retransmitTimer.Stop();

    return response;
}
```

The method SendAndWait is called every time a command telegram is sent.

My issue is the creation of the timer

```
    retransmitTimer = new Timer(RetransmitInterval);
    retransmitTimer.Elapsed += retransmitTimer_Elapsed;
```

This will create a new timer, but the current one is never disposed so it will keep on running? Best scenario it will be stopped.

What is better?

1. Move the creation of the timer to a method that is only called once?
2. Dispose of the current timer and then create a new one in SendAndWait?

Comment: You don't need a timer. Use a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource__ctor_System_TimeSpan_) with Timeout.

Comment: "so it will keep on running" Is this a question or a statement? Did you try it out? Do you still get events fired by the old timer?

Comment: @HimBromBeere It's mostly a question but yes, sometimes there is events fired by the old timer.

Comment: The only really critical detail is that the timer needs to be stopped, so he should have put the Stop() call in a finally block to ensure it is exception-safe.  You'll of course get that automagically when you correctly use the *using* statement.  What you ought to worry more about is what happens when the timer ticks even though the response was received.  That is a pretty likely threading race bug that you can't fix for System.Timers.Timer.  Just make sure it won't blow up when it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap the timer in a `using` statement:

```
public TelegramBase SendAndWait(TelegramBase telegram)
{
    CurrentTelegram = telegram;

    using (Timer retransmitTimer = new Timer(RetransmitInterval))
    {
        retransmitTimer.Elapsed += retransmitTimer_Elapsed;

        //Send telegram
        Send(telegram);

        //Start timer
        retransmitTimer.Start();

        //Wait for response
        var response = WaitForResponse(telegram as StandardTelegram);

        //stop timer
        retransmitTimer.Stop();
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Toby, this is quite misleading The using statement creates a new `retransmitTimer` which hides the property of the same name!

Comment: @Toby Smith That was an option I didn't think of! Looks clean... But the public retransmitTimer should be removed, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Andis59 - yes, very true

Answer (score 0):

From the description of [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8), it seems to be quite heavy object, so initializing it with every message may have pretty large overhead. If you feel like you are struggling with performance, this would be the place to look. You could do some microbenchmarks to time the execution time of the timer constructor compared to the rest of the method.

In your current implementation, the `retransmitTimer` should be local variable contained in a `using` statement, as you can see in the other answer.

If you decide to use one timer per class, then instead of calling the Timer constructor with `RetransmittInterval`, you can use the `Interval` property of existing `Timer` instance to set the interval. With this implementation you should implement `IDisposable` on the class that contains the `SendAndWait` method, and dispose the timer in the `Dispose` method of your class.